# LASSO shrinks all coefficients to 0 in High-dimensional data

Tags: lasso, high-dimensional

I am doing Lasso on a very high dimensional data, over 10K explanatory variables and Lasso shrinks every coefficient to 0, or veery close to it. However, when I do lasso on a small subset of features(50) it works as expected and shrinks only portion on variables to 0.

Has anyone encountered this before and is there any theoretical explanation for this?
[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241471/if-multi-collinearity-is-high-would-lasso-coefficients-shrink-to-0) is similar to mine, however I am not sure if multicollinearity is the main issue, or lasso's inherent problem with p>>n setting.

Comment: How are you setting the regularisation parameter?

Comment: I do cross validation with cv.glmnet in R

Comment: That looks to be some sort of regularisation path algorithm.  What selection criterion are you using (if it is a classification problem, the error rate can be rather brittle)?  How many patterns/samples do you have?  It seems a bit odd as the learning problems are presumably nested, so that is implying that a model without non-zero weights gives better cross-validation performance.

Comment: Its a regression problem with time series data. I have 350 observations in total, of which I use 250-300 for training. The dependent variable is the growth rate of economic variable, so my guess was that with large dataset Lasso is unable to differentiate between the signal and the noise, so it shrinks everything to 0, however this is very intuitive, that's why I asked if there is more formal explanation for this.

Comment: I take it it is a very noisy problem where none of the attributes are highly informative (were the 50 attributes a random sample?)

Comment: For a given value of the regularization parameter, $\lambda$, if a model with all-zero weights had a better value of the regularised loss using all of the features, then it would also have a better value for the problem with only 50 features, so I suspect the problem lies with the method used to select the regularisation parameter.

Comment: Could you maybe suggest a method other than cross-validation in order to choose penalization parameter? I think restricting lasso to return at least some non-zero coefficients to work. To answer the first question those 50 parameters are not random, they are chosen according to econ theory and they are quite informative. the thing is those 50 are also included in larger dataset.

Comment: No cross-validation is fine.  I think the problem is that there are feature subsets that have a lower regularised loss than those 50 on the training set (probably a different set of attributes for each fold), so LASSO picks them instead, but they give a bad cross-validation estimate, because they are only spuriously related to the response, which means that the cross-validation procedure chooses a different regularisation parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. The different subsets of variables may require different set of regularization parameters, but lasso in the end chooses the overall best one. I ran new lasso on whole dataset with the optimal lambda from smaller version. Thanks for help!